# Count number of occurence of different items

Tags: mysql

The table stores the name of the student that has failed a subject in any exam as and when it is conducted . so there may be duplicate records since its timeline is throughout a whole year. the subjects are static say 2 ( maths, science). I need the count of number of times a student has failed in each sub throughout the year.

my query:

```
select a.name,
       (select count(*) 
          from student
         where name = a.name 
           and subject = 'maths'
       ) as maths,
       (select count(*) 
          from student
         where name = a.name 
           and subject = 'science'
       ) as science
  from student a
 group by name
```

Although my query works , it is not efficient when the number of subjects are more than two. 
P.S. I know the structure of the table good be better. ?But this is an assignment.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEYPW.png)

EDIT: **The problem is, the number of subjects are about 10**. What would be the best query then? Should I store them in an array or a separate table something like that?

Thanks a ton!! :) Have a happy day :)

Comment: will you share your mark with me if I give you the answer? By the way there are plenty of answers on this question on SO (see pivot tables)

Answer (score 1):

Use case expressions, here you can use SUM()

```
select a.name
     , SUM(case when subject = 'maths' then 1 else 0 end) as maths
     , SUM(case when subject = 'science' then 1 else 0 end) as science
from student a
group by a.name
```

or take advantage of COUNT() {*which does NOT count NULL*}

```
select a.name
     , COUNT(case when subject = 'maths' then 1 end) as maths
     , COUNT(case when subject = 'science' then 1 end) as science
from student a
group by a.name
```

or you can include "else NULL" when using COUNT()

Comment: Even more simpler for mysql `sum(subject = 'maths')`

Comment: I prefer explicit expressions as they are more "self documenting". Brief code isn't always the best code.

Comment: What do i do when the number of subjects are about 10? Thanks for the time btw :)

Comment: Simply add one case expression for each column. Start by cop th ing one row, paste it n times, then alter the subject name of each row to suit.

Comment: There are different ways to "pivot" data from rows to columns but this case expression approach works in mysql as well as any other SQL compliant dbms.